# CSS absolutely positioned menus on M&S's mobile website, how?

Tags: css

Not sure if this is the appropriate place to ask this, if not, where? It is a code question, but the code is on a website and hard to paste here.

I'm looking at M&S's mobile site, and their slide in menu system to be specific. If you go to http://www.marksandspencer.com in Chrome, open the dev tools and use the device toolbar, it should display as if on a mobile device.

The menu is series of `div`'s inside a `nav`. The `div`'s are `position: absolute;`, but somehow the content doesn't get cut off at the bottom, the page expands to the height of the menu, even when it's way past the bottom of the footer.

Obviously positioning an element absolutely takes it out of the normal flow, and so would be cut off at the bottom of the footer.

Can anyone see how they've managed to achieve this..? That is, having their absolutely positioned `div`'s not cut off. I can't see any manual setting of a `height` property anywhere.

**Update**

To see the effect, go to the home page, set the viewport width to about 500px, then open the menu, clicking on 'Men' then 'Clothing'. This leads to the menu being higher than the content of the page.

Looking at the `div` with classes `mcp-nav-primary__submenu-container is-active` you can see it's `position: absolute;`.

I'm not asking for someone to write code for me.

I'm asking if anyone can see how M&S have achieved this effect..?

Comment: On all the pages I tried the page was higher than the menu, so nothing could be cut off. Do you have an example?

Comment: @Paulie_D Allow me to correct you. I am in no way asking others to write code for me. The answer to my question doesn't need to involve code at all (just like the one you link to doesn't). My question is how does M&S achieve something, and a perfectly good answer might be "by applying method X". I could then research method X. I am genuinely interested in the answer, and honestly think others might be too, which is what SO is all about. It does often feel like some people see a question with no code and want to find a way to be condescending.

Comment: @BjörnTantau Thanks for taking a look, yeah you have to find a short page, then expand the menu. I'll post an example when I get to work tomorrow.

Comment: @BjörnTantau If you go to the home page, set the viewport width to about 500px, then open the menu, clicking on 'Men' then 'Clothing'. This leads to the menu being higher than the content of the page. I'll update my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You learn something new every day. Apparently nothing has to be done to achieve this. The window expands by itself. Note however that the height of the body and html does not expand. And if you set `overflow: hidden` on the body it is cut off as you expected.

See this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/uhqtk13a/

Comment: It's funny, I was looking at their website at the same time you posted this, and was just coming to the same conclusion in my head. Thanks for this, well worth posting on SO - we've both learnt something new today!